# Login and Register in bootboxjs popup using Laravel

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a Login and Register popup window using Bootboxjs which is opening properly but whenever i put wrong credentials (email or password) the modal window disappears. When I open login modal again I get error message on modal window but I want to ensure that modal window should not disappear if there are any validation failures or wrong credentials message.

Comment: May be you would want to share the code so that we can take a look and suggest something

Comment: how can i share code here ?

Comment: you can copy paste the part which has issues or you can share a public link where the code can be accessed